# The mysqld_multi binary is not found in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

I've installed MySQL 5.7 on Centos 7.1.1503 following the instructions at:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html

I need to start multiple instances for MySQL in this machine. According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-multi.html I should use mysqld_multi but it does not found.

I've listed the package contents with:

```
repoquery -l mysql-community-server
```

And there is a /usr/share/man/man1/mysqld_multi.1.gz (the man page) but the binary doesn't exist.

I can't find the way to run multiple instances based on their instructions.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As of MySQL 5.7.13, mysqld_multi and mysqld_multi.server are not installed on platforms supporting systemd.

Check details out here: [Configuring Multiple MySQL Instances Using systemd](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-management-using-systemd.html#systemd-multiple-mysql-instances)